# Reading multiple space-delimited text files from a folder in R

Tags: r, import

I have 100 `space-delimited` text files in a folder. Each text file has a paragraph of text in it. I wish to extract the data in a data frame with `column 1` as `File ID` and `Column 2` as the corresponding text paragraph.

This is what I have tried so far but failed to extract the text paragraph in the desired format.

```
lf <- list.files(path = "", pattern = "'*.txt", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)
data <- lapply(lf, read.table, sep="", header=FALSE)
```

A sample text file looks like this:

"Yeah, and and repeated phone calls is I call in on something I continuously ask if there's a promotional deal going on Dvr's because I've had some problems with the hopper and the delays and today. I get another bill or exchanging hopper enjoys better for Dvr's."

The output I'm getting is a list:

```
[[1]]
     V1  V2  V3       V4    V5    V6 V7 V8   V9 V10 V11       V12 V13          V14 V15 V16     V17
1 Yeah, and and repeated phone calls is  I call  in  on something   I continuously ask  if there's
  V18         V19  V20   V21 V22   V23     V24  V25 V26  V27      V28  V29 V30    V31 V32 V33
1   a promotional deal going  on Dvr's because I've had some problems with the hopper and the
     V34 V35    V36 V37 V38     V39  V40 V41        V42    V43    V44    V45 V46    V47 V48 V49
1 delays and today.   I get another bill  or exchanging hopper enjoys better for Dvr's.
```

I wish to get it in a data frame format as:

```
File ID         Text

file1.txt       Yeah, and and repeated phone calls...
```

Any pointers on what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assume we don't know what your files look like. Show us at least the first few relevant lines of one of the files.

Comment: your `sep` argument may need a space. Like `sep=" "`

Comment: Since you have `include.dirs`, your subsequent `lapply` will choke if you have directories, which I'm inferring you do based on `recursive=TRUE`. However, since you haven't provided any output, I can only speculate ...

Comment: @RomanLuštrik - Added a sample text file with the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (you do not want to have spaces as the delimiters since there are many of them in your paragraphs):

```
dat <- setNames( lapply(lf, read.table, sep="|", header=FALSE), lf)
```

Choose a separator that you suspect will not be in the text. I'm afraid that `sep=""` was a bad choice because it gets interpreted as the default for read.table which is "whitespace". The "title" of the entry for each file should be the file name.

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust...its working like a dream for a subset of files. For the rest of the files, its throwing an error as logi(0) instead of the extracted text. Any inputs on this?

Comment: Not as presented. The error messages are usually more informative, but sadly people just see the word error and don't look at the rest of the message.

Comment: Just tweaked the code a bit to get the result as desired. unlist(setNames(lapply(lf, read.delim, sep="|", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = F), lf))